# If-statement behaving strange

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
var test = _myDictionary.ContainsKey(myKey); 
if (!test) 
{ 
        Logger.Error("My log message"); 
        throw new ApplicationException("My exception message"); 
}
```

The dictionary contains the key. When debugging, the value of `test` is `true`

What happens, is that the code jumps directly to the `throw` statement, skipping the call to `Logger`, while it really shouldn't do neither - it should just skip the whole block and continue execution.

I've replaced the source completely from repository, I've cleaned and rebuilt numerous times, to no avail.

However, when I changed my code to

```
if (test)
{
     // my code
}
else
{
        Logger.Error("My log message"); 
        throw new ApplicationException("My exception message"); 
}
```

everything works as expected.

Any ideas what might be going on here? It works as it currently is, but I won't rest easy unless I know what might be cause this.

**UPDATE:** I deleted my .suo file and some binaries in the output  folder which were not deleted even if I cleaned the solution. After this, it seems to work fine

Comment: Sounds like the debugger is attached to an old version of the code. Tried rebooting the machine?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I assume you're kidding

Comment: These kind of questions are un answerable unless you provide a short but complete sample reproducing the problem.

Comment: What if you enter a third line of code inside your block?

Comment: @PatrickHofman [The First Rule of Programming: It's Always Your Fault](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/) not the compiler, or OS or whatsoever :)

Comment: restart your visual studio and try again

Comment: What?? Why was this put on hold? There's nothing in this question that suggests the user hadn't tried any obvious solutions first!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can happen sometimes when the assembly and its PDB gets out of sync. When you're debugging, the debugger actually reads the relevant information from the PDB file, and not directly from your source file.

You should simply try and rebuild the project (or manually Clean then Build), then try again.

**EDIT** I misread your question, where you said you already tried rebuilding. In this case, during Debugging, go to **Debug → Windows → Modules** window, and make sure the symbol file that is loaded is in fact the correct one (e.g. loaded from the same `bin\Debug` location):
[image]

Comment: It's loading up to date PDBs, since this happens in a unit test session. I deleted all test sessions from the disk to make sure. I've rebooted the computer and thus Visual Studio. The error re-occurred when I reverted my changes which made things work in the first place. So I'm pretty sure the code is running on updated code